# hotspot set number of users programmatically

Tags: android, android-wifi, hotspot

i've used a method to create a hotspot and it's working

but i need to set a specific number of maximum connections that will be in this hotspot

thanks in advance

My current code :

```
private boolean configHotspot(String name,String pass) {
    WifiConfiguration wifiCon = new WifiConfiguration();
    wifiCon.SSID = name;
    wifiCon.preSharedKey = pass;
    wifiCon.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.SHARED);
    wifiCon.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
    wifiCon.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
    wifiCon.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
    try
    {
        Method setWifiApMethod = wifimanager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);
        boolean apstatus=(Boolean) setWifiApMethod.invoke(wifimanager, wifiCon,true);
        return apstatus;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```